# How to resize Android Package file?

Tags: android

My file is 30mb and I want to resize it. Is there a app or something?

```
The problem is that the file is 30mb.
```

Comment: More details needed .

Comment: My apk is 30 MB. I want to shorten the size to at least 10.

Comment: If that's the only requirement then just take the first third of it ;-)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: What makes the apk size 30 mb ? Only class files or some additional resource files like video , audio, big bitmap images something like that?

Comment: Well I added lightweight launcher features to it, features found on Apex and stuff. I do not know how they keep their apk size to a minimum of 5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Proguard to reduce the size of the APK.
   [What is ProGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444554/android-what-is-proguard-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-it/29444637#29444637)
2. Remove unnecessary resources that are not referred or used in the application.
3. Use 9 patch images instead of creating separate resources for different sizes.
4. Optimise your PNGs if they are heavy.
5. maybe host your videos (If heavy in size) on Cloud, may also reduce the size of APK.